# Truffle Test Console Logging

Tags: truffle, testing, truffle-test, truffle-console

I'm having some trouble with Truffle logging configuration. During tests, each submitted transaction and its hash is logged on the console and this one becomes full of useless messages that disturb the important results.

I've tried to look up the text of these logs within the node_modules folder in order to comment the console.log("Transaction submitted successfully. Hash: ...") but I haven't found anything. If there's any way I can configure this or at least remove it from the packages code, please let me know.

Thank you in advance.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this some new kind of feature? I have never seen this before. It just started doing it today. Also, truffle test works even if ganache is not running, so I think it automatically runs its own virtual chain?